# How to get the datasource information from Kendo UI dragend event?

Tags: kendo-ui, drag, linechart, kendo-chart

This is the code for the line chart which has drag function to highlight some data. I would like to get the datasource information in the dragEnd event,currently I am just getting screenX and screenY values.

```
function createChart(data) {

                $("#TimeSeriesPlot").kendoChart({

                    title: {
                        text: series_name.toUpperCase()
                    },
                    dataSource :{
                        data:data.timeseries,
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: "line",
                         field:"v",
                        categoryField:"ts",
                   }],
                     valueAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            format: "{0}"
                        },title:{
                            text: "value"
                        },
                        line: {
                            visible: false
                        },

                     },
                    categoryAxis: {
                     labels: {
                      type: "date",

                    },  
                   tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                       // shared:true,
                         template: "${category} - ${value}"
                    },

                    plotAreaClick: onPlotAreaClick,
                    seriesClick:onSeriesClick ,
                    dragStart:onDragStart ,
                    drag:onDrag,
                    dragEnd:onDragEnd 

                });
            }
    }

    function onSeriesHover(e) {
            console.log(kendo.format("Series hover :: {0} ({1}): {2}",
                e.series.name, e.category, e.value));
            }


    function onSeriesClick(e){
           //   console.log(selected_anamolies);
             //  console.log(e.category);
               selected_anamolies.push("ts",e.category);
               selected_anamolies.push("v",e.value);
    }

    function onDragStart(e){

           //  console.log("dragstart"+e.axisRanges.ts);

            //   console.log("dragstart"+e.sender._highlight._points[0].value);
           //     console.log("dragstart"+e.sender._highlight._points[0].category);


    }

    function onDrag(e){

            var Rect = kendo.geometry.Rect;
            var draw = kendo.drawing;
            prevloc=e.originalEvent.x.startLocation;
            currentloc=e.originalEvent.x.location;

            var rect=new Rect([prevloc,50],[currentloc-prevloc,150]);
            var path = draw.Path.fromRect(rect,{  stroke: null,fill:{color:"#d3f1fb",opacity:0.2}});
            var chart = e.sender;
    //   var surface = draw.Surface.create($("#surface"));
            chart.surface.draw(path);
                        //                        
    }


    function onDragEnd(e){
      console.log(dragEnd)

    }
```

Comment: What are you dragging, a grid row, a list element,...?

Comment: I am dragging in linechart to highlight some data and store the data